# Unity 5.3 GUI Button Won't Call OnClick Event

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So I'm trying to make a game with a title screen that you click to load the scene called `Game`. The button that I am using, created in the editor, doesn't work for whatever reason. When I create the button using code (Below), it does work. Why can't I use the editor to create my button and then call a function using `OnClick` by assigning it in the editor?

If I am going about making a 'click to play' title screen wrong please help me.
Thanks in advance!

```
GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width * .25, Screen.height * .4, Screen.width * .5, Screen.height * .1), "Test")
```

Comment: Can you post the snap of the button with inspector?

Comment: Please clarify. Does 'snap' mean OnClick?

Comment: Oh. My bad there. Anyway, since this is a title screen, it is not resource intensive. Because of this, I decided that I would just make a large sprite that covered the entire screen and make it render a transparency. So in a way, I have solved my problem.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use [Unity UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making an empty GameObject and adding a box collider and a script. The script just calls an `OnClick` event like so:

```
function OnClick {
    //Code goes here
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(X, Y, width,height), "Button")) {
            Function();
        }
```

this will check if button is pressed and call function defined.

Comment: The issue with this is that I want to make my button in the editor, so I have more control over it.

Comment: This code works perfectly fine for me. In fact, I had tried it before posting.

Comment: than whats the problem? why can't you add button in editor ,Goto GameObject> Ui >Button, and than Under OnClick(), of button component, press + button and just drag a gameObject on which you have attached your Script(which contains the function to be call on click) and select the function. But make sure to make your  function public( public void Name()) else it will not be shown in list of functions.

Comment: I am not able to click the button when I do that.